# Using filter expression on Dynamo DB index

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We know that we can apply filter expression in the Query operation of the dynamo db. I am trying the same when i query a index,Is it possible to use filter expression with indexes ? i am not getting any results or filtering here. Below is the code snippet

```
Map<String, String> expressionAttributeNames = new HashMap<>();
        expressionAttributeNames.put("#student_status", "status");


    QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("school_id = :schoolId")
            .withFilterExpression("#student_status <> OUT")
            .withNameMap(expressionAttributeNames)
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                    .withString(":schoolId", schoolId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Filter Expression works just the same on a table or a GSI. If you want to query a GSI rather than the table you need to specify `.withIndexName`

Comment: I have done it , Query is getting executed but the "filtering" is not happening . I still get the un filtered data.